# Git: remote: Repository not found

Tags: git, repository

I can't pull or push anything from a remote repository. I do have the correct rights.

```
C:\Users\Stijn\Dropbox\Fissa\website\alpha 0.3>git remote -v
origin  https://github.com/jeroenmager/Fissa (fetch)
origin  https://github.com/jeroenmager/Fissa (push)

C:\Users\Stijn\Dropbox\Fissa\website\alpha 0.3>git pull origin master
remote: Repository not found.
fatal: repository 'https://github.com/jeroenmager/Fissa/' not found
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the awnser. I was logged in with my old account and also my new account. I know this makes no sense but inviting both accounts worked, while inviting both accounts sepperately didn't. Thank you all for your help anyways

Answer (score 1):

The repo really doesn’t seem to exist, [see the web interface](https://github.com/jeroenmager/Fissa).

Comment: It does, its a private repo. I can acces it without any problem

Comment: So maybe git can’t access it? What kind of authentication do you use?